# What is thirumuruga thirumangalya yagam?

Tags: shiva, puja

What is a pooja conducted at pradaosham called thirumuruga thirumangalya yagam? Pradosham  conducted in temple.

Below are the pics

[image] [image]

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.stackechange ! It is unclear what you are asking. Add some more details about that yagam or the pooja. Did you ask about this pooja at the temple?

Comment: Who is Tirumuruga? Is he Kartikeya?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes. Tiru means shree. Muruga means Kartikeya

Comment: Something to do with marriage of Skanda?

Comment: @SreeCharan but who is behind Linga in pic? Kumara or Goddess?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think it is kumara swami. I think what we see are his faces. He is six faced in many temples. Is there a need of a larger image?